# How to resolve hostname in Cordova App?

Tags: android, cordova, dns

I am developing a android app using cordova. The app communicate to the server using socketio. The server resides in Local area network.
The app is able to communicate to server using server's IP.
What i want:
The app should be able to communicate using server's hostname (server is running Ubuntu 16.04, if it matters).

I have already tried following plugins in cordova:

## https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-dns

## https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-dns-plugin

It may be working for websites but i want local server's hostname to be resolved. The server's hostname is 'inspiron' and i tried with 'inspiron' and 'inspiron.local' both.

Comment: Your DNS-Servers configuration could be interesting here. Could you add the relevant parts? Seeing what goes on in Wireshark could also help to identify your problem...